# extract data from text file to form

Tags: php

I have a text file on my local server including different data. I would like to have a php file to extract content of the text file to the textboxes of my html form which I have designed it before?

B.txt ----> PHP-----> form.html

Could you please help me?

Comment: use `<input type='hidden'>` ??

Comment: you sould look at `fopen`, but your really need to expand on your question this is very loose

Comment: I know how can I read and echo content of text file in a html. But I would like to write content of my text file in certain text boxes in my html form. For example consider, a user have stored his data as a text file in my local server. I have prepared a username/password form. If user put his password, How can I extract his data which have been saved as text file before and show it again in my html form?

Comment: @hooman How did you format your text file?

Comment: The Stackoverflow community won't just do it for you - but we will help you with any specific issues you have trying to code what you want. Please try to do it yourself, and if you have problems then come back to us.

Comment: Very simple for example: First row: Name, Second row: email and...

Comment: @hooman you need to look up these things json_encode, json_decode, fopen, you can put data you can read data and its in a version that js can read as well, yeah i just saw an answer get posted but this is really something you need to know to progress with this ... also I HATE FORMS so thats why i want you to learn on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the contents of your file.

```
$file = file_get_contents("/path/to/file/B.txt");
```

And then you can use it to fill up your form.

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you have in your file and the form code.

Comment: how can show  data in text file  through  different textboxes?

Comment: @hooman Just do the same thing with that file. As for filling up your form, I really need to know what your text files look like.